# Insert numbers into mongo-db collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am currently learning Mongo DB and trying to insert numbers into my "numbers" collection (in mongo command shell).

```
//This works : 
db.numbers.insertMany([{"number":1},{"number":2}]);

//This doesn't 
db.numbers.insertMany([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

(1) Does that mean that number is not a valid document or I am missing a very basic concept ?

(2) Why Mongo-db is not assigning Object-ID to numbers automatically in this case ?

Comment: "Does that mean that number is not a valid document" - yes. It's not a document, it's a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
//actual output from Mongoshell version 4.2.6 command line
> db.numbers.insertMany([{"number":1},{"number":2}]);
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf03"),
                ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf04")
        ]
}
> db.numbers.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf03"), "number" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf04"), "number" : 2 }
> db.numbers.insertOne({number:[1,2,3,4,5,6]});
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedId" : ObjectId("5f79fa9ed04cd9e2b3acbf05")
}
> db.numbers.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf03"), "number" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79fa89d04cd9e2b3acbf04"), "number" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79fa9ed04cd9e2b3acbf05"), "number" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] }
>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mallik but it doesn't answer my question, in your case you are creating another collection named "number" inside "numbers" collection.

I am having doubt why following line is not working : 
db.numbers.insertMany([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

Comment: what is the error you are getting for db.numbers.insertMany([1,2,3,4,5,6]);? I think the error will answer your query.

Comment: I get this error in 4.4.1 db.numbers.insertMany([1,2,3,4,5,6]); > db.version()
4.4.1
> db.numbers.insertMany([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
uncaught exception: Error: argument passed to addIdIfNeeded is not an object :